# Google ReCaptcha V3 - Missing required parameters: sitekey

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to implement [Google ReCaptcha V3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) (which is a different implementation from V2, so please don't mark as duplicate).

Here's my page's JS script that initializes the ReCaptcha (Replacing `MyKey` with my actual key I registered [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create)):

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
       grecaptcha.ready(function () {
           grecaptcha.execute('MyKey', {action: 'homepage'});
       });
    });
</script>
```

When loading the page I get the following error in the browser's dev console:

> Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `reCAPTCHA_site_key`
on `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key`
with your actual key.